# Type function with generic callbacks that match

Tags: typescript

```
const example = <a, b> (o: (a) => b, c: (b) => a) => {

}

example(() => 1, (n) => n)
```

I'm looking for `n` to be assigned to number, but I get no warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Playing with this in the Typescript Playground, I came up with the following that seems to resolve the types the way you expect:

```
const example = <a, b>(o: ((arg1: a) => b), c: ((arg2: b) => a)) => {}

example(() => 1, (n) => n);
```

There are two differences here:

1. I wrapped the `example` function argument types in parentheses to make them a little clearer (at least in my mind - I was having trouble wrapping my head around functions inside functions), and
2. I added argument names (`arg1` and `arg2`)

I'm reasonably sure that this is what you intended - I believe that a function type expression requires argument names. For example, the following results in a "Parameter has a name but no type. Did you mean 'arg0: a'?" error in the playground:

```
type f1 <a, b>(a) => b;
```